# Guardar lista en una variable desde un array php

Tags: php, array

Hola amigos hoy tengo una duda de como lograr extraer y guardar una lista desde un array .

Este es el código que estoy usando:

```
$datos = Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] =>
Array ( [0] => _22938513 [1] => _45984789 [2] => _45966879 [3] => _46048227 [4] => _26767583 [5] => _45137827 [6] => _41538617 [7] => _45860863 [8] => _45543708 [9] => _41792665 [10] => _28212331 [11] => _44209003 [12] => _23660986 [13] => _45567819 [14] => _45539598 [15] => _46004147 [16] => _45930599 [17] => _45523079 [18] => _46041147 [19] => _33272309 [20] => _45935183 [21] => _45979315 [22] => _10132780 [23] => _28618737 [24] => _34169477 [25] => _37682775 [26] => _45486965 [27] => _36919699 [28] => _36606257 [29] => _45506299 [30] => _45937685 [31] => _40691491 [32] => _45993339 [33] => _45870235 [34] => _45941369 [35] => _19510939 [36] => _45917853 [37] => _45652307 [38] => _45345349 [39] => _45992177 [40] => _41820795 [41] => _45579257 [42] => _26216871 [43] => _45668761 [44] => _45541170 [45] => _45919709 [46] => _45553620 [47] => _45585261 [48] => _46033219 [49] => _45811439 ) );

$contenido="";
foreach($datos as $row){ 
    $contenido .= $row.PHP_EOL; 
}
Echo $contenido;
```

El resultado que deseo lograr es :
_22938513
_45984789
_45966879

Este es el mensaje de error . 
 "Notice: Array to string conversion"

Espero alguna idea del por que con este tipo de array el método foreach no funciona y cual es la mejor manera . y disculpas si no esta bien redadtado . es que use el celular .

Comment: Intento guardar el contenido del array $datos en la variable $contenido  usando foreach.

Comment: El resultado seria _45966879 o sea todos las numeraciones . en una lista

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si el array es siempre igual, no veo motivo para complicarse la vida. Se podría solucionar con una sola línea usando [**`implode`**](http://php.net/manual/es/function.implode.php):

```
#El array
$datos = array ( array ( array ( '_22938513', '_45984789', '_45966879' )) ); 

#La línea     
echo implode(" ",$datos[0][0]);
```

**Salida:**

```
_22938513 _45984789 _45966879
```

*That's all folks!*

Comment: Si realmente es una forma simple de resolverlo . igual mientras mas soluciones mas se logra aprender . gracias por tu aporte .

Answer (score 3):

El problema es como accedes al array donde se encuentran los datos, ya que tienes un array de un elemento que contiene otro array de un elemento y este último contiene 50 elementos con tus datos, que es donde debe incidir el recorrido del bucle.

En formato php tu array sería equivalente a este ejemplo:

```
$datos = array ( array ( array ( _22938513, _45984789, _45966879 )) );
```

Y con el foreach recorreríamos en este caso el array de datos accediendo al primer elemento de los dos arrays que lo contienen.

```
$contenido="";
foreach($datos[0][0] as $row){ 
    $contenido .= $row.PHP_EOL; 
}
echo $contenido;

//Resultado:
_22938513 _45984789 _45966879
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta igual me da un error .: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: El problema estaba en la forma de recorer el array .

Answer (score 3):

Una solución genérica sería mediante una función recursiva, que compruebe si un determinado elemento es o no un *array*. Podemos hacerlo tanto en profundidad como en altura ... a falta de mas datos, y puesto que es mas simple, he optado por hacerlo en profundidad:

```
function array_concat( $origen ) {
  $ret = [ ];

  array_concat_to( $origen, $ret );

  return $ret;
}

function array_concat_to( $origen, &$destino ) {
  foreach( $origen as $valor ) {
    if( is_array( $valor ) ) {
      if( count( $valor ) > 0 ) array_concat_to( $valor, $destino );
    } else {
      $destino[] = $valor;
    }
  }
}

$test = [
  [ 1, 2, 3 ],
  4,
  [ ],
  5,
  [ 4, 5 ]
];

$result = array_concat( $test );

var_dump( $result );
```

Salida:

> array(7) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(2) [2]=> int(3) [3]=> int(4) [4]=> int(5) [5]=> int(4) [6]=> int(5) }

Comment: Excelente respuesta